# Prompt not displaying Hostname for AIX's KSH

Tags: ksh, aix, hostname

Similar to question 1171663, AIX appears to not have the $HOSTNAME option available.  $hname and $hostname are also non-existent.  Other than doing the following within .profile -

```
export HOSTNAME=`hostname`
```

Is there an official manner where AIX users should be capable of getting the proper results when using:

```
PS1="${HOSTNAME}:\${PWD##*/} \$ "
```

Comment: That's the way I would do it (except that I would use `$()` instead of backticks). It probably doesn't need to be exported, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it, but for the hostname - can't you mix your first example with your second?

```
PS1="`hostname`:\${PWD##*/} \$ "
```

Not sure about PWD bit though?

Comment: There's probably no reason to re-execute `hostname` each time the prompt is issued.

Comment: Exactly.  I would rather just gather the hostname once instead of every single time.  It's neglectable, but good practice to do so.

Comment: I don't get both of these comments. hostname is evaluated only once in monojohnny's reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export HOSTNAME=`uname -n`
```